# Non simply connected HyperKähler 4-manifolds without ALE metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds, gauge-theory

In a [1989 paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214443066) Peter Kronheimer showed that each simply connected HyperKähler 4-manifold possesses an ALE metric. What do we know about the non-simply connected cases?

Answer (score 10):

I may be missing something :-) I'm not seeing where Kronheimer shows
$$
\text{hyper-Kähler + simply connected} \Rightarrow \text{ALE}
\tag{?}
$$
as you claim. But in [2] he shows that "*every hyper-Kähler ALE 4-manifold is isometric to a member of one of the families obtained in* [1]." As said members are (I believe) simply connected, this means that
$$
\text{hyper-Kähler + ALE} \Rightarrow \text{simply connected}
\tag{!}
$$
which appears to answer your question. Also of interest: [3] which constructs ALF, ALG, ALH,... metrics on (mostly, but not always, simply connected, hyper-Kähler) 4-manifolds; [4]; and [5], Remark 4.5.

[1] [The construction of ALE spaces as hyper-Kähler quotients](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214443066)
[2] [A Torelli-type theorem for gravitational instantons](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214443067)
[3] [A Kummer construction for gravitational instantons](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5133)
[4] [Quotients of gravitational instantons](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2442)
[5] [ALE Ricci-flat Kähler metrics and deformations of quotient surface singularities](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2672)

Answer (score 4):

"Peter Kronheimer showed that each simply connected HyperKähler 4-manifold possesses an ALE metric."

This is false as stated. K3 surface, or the Taub-NUT space, are simply connected 4-manifolds which are not ALE. What is true is that a complete hyperkaehler 4-manifold with $L^2$-integrable curvature and maximal volume growth is ALE.
The "volume growth" condition means that the volume of a ball of radius $r$ grows as $r^4$ (the growth exponent for a Ricci-flat manifold is always bounded by the dimension). For K3 the growth is obviously zero (it is compact); for Taub-NUT the exponent is 3.

Comment: What a nice comment :)