# Is there any open Ricci-flat ALE 4-manifold other than Hyper-Kahler ALE 4-manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds, gauge-theory

Concerning my previous question [Non simply connected HyperKähler 4-manifolds without ALE metrics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138937/non-simply-connected-Hyper-Kahler-4-manifolds-without-ale-metrics) the following question occurred to me:

Is there any open Ricci-flat ALE 4-manifold other than Hyper-Kahler ALE 4-manifolds?

Answer (score 1):

See Ioana Suvaina, [ALE Ricci-flat metrics and deformations of quotient surface singularities](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2672), Remark 4.5
(this reference was also in one of the answers to your previous question).

Comment: dissrtation of Hugues Auvray, https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00750891/document